# how to send "Sharedpreferences" info to other device using SMS?

Tags: android, sms, sharedpreferences

I am working on MDM project and trying to remotely control other device through sending rules within SMS.

I wonder if there is a possible way to send sharedpreference information that one device has in its phone to other device through sending SMS.

All I know about SMS API is just to receive and get sender's number and text contents in String type.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sharedpreference is xml format file.It's text content.You can read it via stream and send it by sms.

Comment: Thanks. Now I wonder where and how to get that sharedprefrence contents? And, now I realize that it's gonna maybe be very long long text and it's gonna be MMS SMS.

Comment: You know , the Sharedpreference contains key and value, may be you can just get the keys and values you need and send them, not the whole file.I dont know if Sharedpreference has limit of size, if the file is so big and you need send the whole file, sms is not a good way.